# Recurrence relation of quicksort depending on its pivot

Tags: recurrence-relation, quicksort

I understand how the recurrence relation of quicksort is

$T(n) = 2T(n/2)+\mathcal{O}(n)$,

but if we are guaranteed a certain pivot, for example $n/4$th smallest element to be the pivot every time, how would it affect the recurrence relation? I would love some insight on how to approach analyzing such performance.

Comment: Your recurrence relation only holds if the split is always even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the 4th smallest element is always chosen as a pivot then the recurrence relation is 
$$T(n) = T(n/4)+T(3n/4) + \mathcal{O}(n).$$

If we look at the recursion tree we will see that the left branch has $\log_4 n$ depth and the right has $\log_{4/3} n$ depth. At each step, until the leftmost branch terminates, the sum of levels is equal to $cn \in \mathcal{O}(n)$, for the remaining the levels the sum $\leq cn$. Therefore in the worst case calculation, if we assume all have depth $\log_{4/3} n$ and have $cn$ cost then the cost is;

$$c n \log_{4/3} \in \mathcal{O}(n\log n)$$

Comment: **Note:** A would like to draw the recursion tree, but it is hard. See [1/10:9/10](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~nodari/teaching/f15/Notes/Topic-10/Fig-7-4-quicksort-1-9-recursion-tree.jpg) image from Cormen et.al's book. You may replace 9 with 3 and 4 with 10.

Answer (score 0):

In quicksort the recurrence relation solely depends on the pivot element. The reason we have it's time complexity as O(n^2) rather than O(nlogn) is the possibility of chosing the worst possible element in every iteration (arises in scenarios when a sorted array is given). In case the pivot element is decided in a way that it divides the array in any way (even in 9/10 and 1/10 or any such unequal partition) then too the complexity of the quicksort would decrease to O(nlogn).

Comment: This doesn’t quite answer the question: what happens to the recurrence relation, and how to analyze it?